# Django : how to limit the open app?

Tags: python, django

I have several apps on my django project :

```
DJANGO_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # 'django.contrib.gis.db',
    ]

LOCAL_APPS = [
    #'cycliste'                  ,
    #'logger'                    ,
    'position'                  ,
    'reseau'                    ,
    'station'                   ,
    #'trajet'                    ,
    #'useful_functions'          ,
    'velo'                      ,
    #'ville'                     ,
]

INSTALLED_APPS = DJANGO_APPS + LOCAL_APPS
```

My url file is :

```
urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^', include('reseau.urls')),
    url(r'^', include('station.urls')),
    url(r'^', include('velo.urls')),
    url(r'^', include('position.urls')),


]
```

Now, each app is a rest server. I want to start a different app on each of the servers of my cluster.
I see 2 ways to do that :

1. I comment the LOCAL_APPS I don't want on the server
2. I change the urls file, removing the url I don't want to accept

The issue is that I have 6 or 7 apps. For each one of them I just want to be able to start a "station" server, or  a "logger" server. So I need to dynamically change which app is included in LOCAL_APPS at runtime.

I tried to do it through a --settings command, but had no luck. I tried to do it through a specific management.command but without succcess... Finally I think it should be simpler. 
Maybe a test on the settings file ?

How can I dynamically change the INSTALLED_APPS value ?

How can I dynamically change the urlpatterns value ?

Comment: Read from an environment variable?

Answer (score 0):

First, I recommend use [django-environ](https://github.com/joke2k/django-environ) for dynamically var on each "station". Ignore this step if you're already apply `env` to your settings:

```
import environ
env = environ.Env()

env_file = 'path/to/env/file.env'
if exists(env_file):
    environ.Env.read_env(str(env_file))
```

**Dynamically change the INSTALLED_APPS value:**

1) Change by switch settings when start your app:

`python manage.py runserver --settings=path.to.settings.production.station1`

2) Change by load LOCAL_APPS from env file:

```
LOCAL_APPS = ['your', 'app', 'here']
INSTALLED_APPS = DJANGO_APPS + env.list('LOCAL_APPS', default=LOCAL_APPS)
```

**Dynamically change the urlpatterns value:**

Change `ROOT_URLCONF` in your settings, get from env instead:

```
# Define url config here
ROOT_URLCONF = env('ROOT_URLCONF', default='core.urls.development')
```

Dynamically change the INSTALLED_APPS value: